OperationalError sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
I am working flask and I want to create a database to store my user input. It's been hours now and I'm still getting this error. I made sure my db was created and imported corrected, I also tried db.create_all() in different parts of my code. I have also restarted my system in case this might be an issue, nothing works. I have deleted the empty databases created as well, still doesn't work
Here's my model.py:
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    lastName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum('Male','Female','Other','Prefer not to say'), nullable=False)
    unique_num = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    ph_num = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    reason = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    fam_history = db.Column(db.Enum('Yes', 'No'))
    severity = db.Column(db.Enum('Routine','Moderate','Mild','Urgent','Severe','Emergency'), nullable=False)

This is my app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from models import db, User

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

# Set a secret key for the session
app.secret_key = 'xyztth7768#'

# Create the database tables



@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        firstName = request.form.get('first_name')
        lastName = request.form.get('last_name')
        age = request.form.get('age')
        gender = request.form.get('gender')
        unique = request.form.get('unique_number')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        num = request.form.get('phone_number')
        reason = request.form.get('reason')
        famHist = request.form.get('family_history')
        severity = request.form.get('severity')
        
        if len(unique) < 6:
            flash('Incorrect Number!', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email is incorrect!', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(firstName=firstName, lastName=lastName, age=age, gender=gender, unique_num=unique,
                            email=email, ph_num=num, reason=reason, fam_history=famHist, severity=severity)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Form submitted successfully!')
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def push():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all() 
    app.run(port=5500, debug=True)


db in model.py and db in app.py is different, cause to errorr. You need create one at app.py and import it to model to use

db is defined twice in your code. One time in model.py, and another time in app.py.
The db you are trying to initialize is the one in app.py, for which no table has been defined.
In app.py, just remove the line :
db = SQLAlchemy()

And, also in app.py, keep the :
from models import db

This way, the db initialized in app.py will be the same as the one defined in model.py.
